# Bypass nginx cache if user is authenticated Django

Tags: django, caching, nginx

I'm implementing nginx as a reverse proxy for a Django project. I'm now trying implement nginx's cache config below:

```
proxy_cache_path /var/cache/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_cache:5m max_size=1g inactive=60m;
proxy_temp_path /var/cache/nginx/tmp;

server {
  ...

  location / {
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';

     # cache
     proxy_cache my_cache;
     proxy_cache_min_uses 1;
     proxy_cache_valid 200 302 10m;
     proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;
     proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
     proxy_cache_use_stale error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
     proxy_cache_lock on;

     proxy_hide_header "Set-Cookie";

     add_header X-Proxy-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
  }
}
```

All works great, however I'd like it so that authenticated users are able to bypass the cache, as otherwise when they update the site content, they won't see the changes, only the cached content until it expires.

What would be the best way to approach this?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: caching dynamic content is almost always a bad idea

Comment: The site isn't hugely dynamic, it's just that when an update is made in the admin, the user who makes the amendment will not be able to view the update until the cache has expired (or if they enter nocache in the url bar).

Comment: how many page views do you get per day

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a middleware to set cookie (eg `cachedisable`) in response if user is autheticated else remove that cookie. So that you can put `$cookie_ cachedisable` in nginx conf

```
location / {
    proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_cachedisable $arg_nocache;
    ...
}
```

Whenever you want bypass cache do requests like

```
http://www.example.com/?nocache=true #or if cookie `cachedisable` is present
```

For more info https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-caching-guide/?utm_source=nginx-caching-guide&utm_medium=blog#caching-guide-faq-hole-punch

Comment: Thanks for you help, I understand that you can use the query string to bypass the cache, but for a user to have to remember to add the query string whenever they change something isn't really ideal. I was hoping for a more automated solution

Comment: If that's the only workable solution from nginx, is there a way of having some middleware in Django that always adds the query string if a user is authenticated. Thanks

Comment: In django default, there will be `sessionid` for authenticated users. You can change `$cookie_nocache` to `$cookie_sessionid` .Son no need of `cache=true` in query string. Briefly you can bypass nginx cache through query string or cookie.

Comment: I've just tried your solution and that doesn't work unfortunately. Nothing gets cached :( I've tried ```proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_sessionid;``` and ```proxy_cache_bypass $cookie_sessionid $arg_nocache;```

Comment: nothing gets cached?. You mean not getting the cached result  or still getting cached result?

Comment: I don't get the cached result, the header X-Proxy-Cache shows BYPASS for all requests.

Comment: yeah that is expected, if sessionid in cookie or  nocache in url, it will bypass cache.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused. The caching isn't working as expected with your solution, as it doesn't get the cached result for all requests, irrelevant of whether a user is logged in or not. This is not what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: I will tell a solution,add a middleware to set cookie (eg 'cachedisable') in response if user is autheticated else remove that cookie. So that youcan put `$cookie_ cachedisable` in nginx conf

Comment: Then please accept the answer.it will help others also.